# Help needed......Statistics probability and z table...stuck

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics, descriptive-statistics

The question is:

**An estimated 1.8 million students take on student loans to pay ever-rising tuition and room and board (New York Times, April 17, 2009). It is also known that the average cumulative debt of recent college graduates is about $22,500.

The cumulative debt for college graduates is normally distributed with a standard deviation of $7,000.

Approximately how many recent college graduates have accumulated a student loan of more than $30,000?**

What I've done: 30,000-22500/7000=1.071428571
I then looked this up on the z table but that wouldn't give me the correct answer. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: What number did you get?

Comment: I got .8577 from the z-table

Comment: Then do $(1800000)(1-0.8577)$. If it is clear why, good. If not, I can give some detail about why.

Comment: Thanks,I believe I do need details as to why this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Under the stated assumptions, you calculated correctly the **probability** that a student has debt **less than or equal** to $30000$. This probability is approximately $0.8577$.

So the probability that the debt is **greater** than $30000$ is approximately $1-0.8577$, which is $0.1423$.

You were asked to estimate the **number** of recent college graduates with level of debt $\gt 30000$. You are probably expected to assume that the $1.8$ million counts these, though the wording does not fully support this. But if we assume that there are indeed $1.8$ million in the recent college graduate category, then the number of these with debt $\gt 30000$ should be approximately $(1800000)(0.1423)$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Debt of more than 30000. So the area you should be looking for is $$ 1- \Phi(\frac{30000-22500}{7000})$$